# Speeding up non-vectorized R code

Tags: r

The code below generates the desired output. However, the lack of vectorizing means it runs very slowly. How can I speed it up?

I've put the `dput` results from part of some indicative data.

**Input `dput`s**

1. `StandRef` input

   ```
   structure(list(id = structure(c(43L, 50L, 17L, 45L, 9L, 5L, 49L, 
   33L, 48L, 39L, 71L, 64L, 44L, 47L, 58L, 24L, 15L, 37L, 14L, 11L, 
   26L, 57L, 4L, 30L, 72L, 21L, 23L, 60L, 38L, 59L, 29L, 19L, 6L, 
   46L, 36L, 3L, 63L, 55L, 51L, 35L, 10L, 7L, 16L, 73L, 42L, 52L, 
   41L, 27L, 25L, 61L, 20L, 70L, 53L, 18L, 31L, 22L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 
   40L, 65L, 67L, 28L, 56L, 13L, 32L, 54L, 66L, 68L, 34L, 12L, 69L, 
   62L), .Label = c("ID 1009445", "ID 120763", "ID 133883", "ID 136398", 
   "ID 171850", "ID 192595", "ID 197597", "ID 216406", "ID 21888", 
   "ID 230940", "ID 23777", "ID 282791", "ID 306348", "ID 309745", 
   "ID 326928", "ID 344897", "ID 34974", "ID 350157", "ID 391831", 
   "ID 402479", "ID 43010", "ID 484078", "ID 484697", "ID 537134", 
   "ID 562259", "ID 562455", "ID 567042", "ID 572866", "ID 578945", 
   "ID 595683", "ID 59759", "ID 598460", "ID 603611", "ID 603757", 
   "ID 607991", "ID 60976", "ID 622720", "ID 646989", "ID 656144", 
   "ID 668807", "ID 669435", "ID 720522", "ID 740555", "ID 745499", 
   "ID 746001", "ID 783969", "ID 78979", "ID 792426", "ID 793541", 
   "ID 797860", "ID 806559", "ID 810517", "ID 826054", "ID 837609", 
   "ID 839287", "ID 867918", "ID 869788", "ID 875380", "ID 876870", 
   "ID 882220", "ID 893116", "ID 895909", "ID 899050", "ID 900143", 
   "ID 908100", "ID 912185", "ID 916371", "ID 916620", "ID 957879", 
   "ID 966195", "ID 993247", "ID 998911", "ID 999610"), class = "factor"), 
       region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       2L), location = c(259090L, 559306L, 2227063L, 2369217L, 4026978L, 
       4211264L, 4679449L, 5105226L, 5106345L, 5344670L, 5473601L, 
       5476528L, 5871970L, 6461228L, 6700029L, 6708265L, 7639959L, 
       9297695L, 10254788L, 10328812L, 11102816L, 11568295L, 11720437L, 
       12843457L, 14012506L, 14156669L, 14632300L, 14641938L, 15298211L, 
       15468425L, 15534406L, 16279682L, 16699353L, 17226952L, 17320785L, 
       269017L, 453097L, 828833L, 954610L, 954842L, 1066378L, 1217332L,  
       1253530L, 1277716L, 1292857L, 1337952L, 1439657L, 1452989L, 
       1712345L, 1758035L, 2601630L, 2640359L, 2778095L, 3151129L, 
       3369931L, 3399080L, 3529525L, 3810217L, 3821120L, 3841588L, 
       3901557L, 4111633L, 4220440L, 4528632L, 4665450L, 5099307L, 
       5260242L, 5958770L, 5966356L, 6137405L, 6246065L, 6297231L, 
       6807949L)), .Names = c("id", "region", "location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
   -73L))
   ```
2. Two sample inputs

Sample 1

```
        structure(list(region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
        begin = c(0L, 2259252L, 5092077L, 9158205L, 0L, 135094L, 
        941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L), finish = c(2259252L, 5092077L, 
        9158205L, 20463033L, 135094L, 941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L, 
        7092402L), sed = c(3.98106154985726, 7.51649828394875, 5.15440228627995, 
        2.67456624889746, 7.54309412557632, 4.17413910385221, 7.47043058509007, 
        6.13362524658442, 1.00084994221106)), .Names = c("region", 
        "begin", "finish", "sed"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -9L))
```

Sample 2

```
        structure(list(region = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
        begin = c(0L, 2253252L, 7091077L, 9120205L, 0L, 135094L, 
        941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L), finish = c(2253252L, 7091077L, 
        9120205L, 17463033L, 135094L, 941813L, 5901391L, 6061324L, 
        7092402L), sed = c(3.31830840984048, 1.38014704208403, 6.13049140975458, 
        2.10349875097134, 0.48170587509345, 0.13058713509175, 9.13509713513509, 
        6.13047153058701, 3.81734081501503)), .Names = c("region", 
        "begin", "finish", "sed"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -9L))
```

**Unvectorized Code**

```
matchLocationsToRegions <- function(path) {     
# get list of data files (around 500 of these; only dput of 2 given: sample262519 and sample252519)
setwd(path,sep="",collapse=NULL))
data_files <- list.files()

# read in template file with complete regional boundaries
standRef <- read.table(paste(path, "StandRef.txt",sep="",collapse=NULL), header=TRUE, sep="\t")

# pre-allocate a df with row dimensions of standRef and num of columns according to num of data files
sediment.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(standRef),ncol=length(data_files)))
colnames(sediment.df) <- data_files
rownames(sediment.df) <- standRef[,1]

# create a counter for columns filled
col_counter <- 1    

for (file in data_files) {
    # read in current, processed data
    sample <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")          

    # pre-allocate vectors for sedimentation data vector
    sed <- rep(NA, nrow(standRef))

    # create a variable to track end boundary for a particular sample_ID
    end_tracker <- 1

    for (region in 1:2) {               # actually 10 regions but just done 2 here
        # subset standRef and sample by region code
        standRef.region <- standRef[which(standRef$region == region),]
        sample.region <- sample[which(sample$region == region),]

        for (i in 1:nrow(sample.region))
        {
            # create a dataframe - locations - that includes: 
            # 1) those indices of standRef.region in which the value of the location column is greater than the value of the ith row of the begin column of sample.region
            # 2) those indices of standRef.region in which the value of the location column is less than the value of the ith row of the finish column of sample.region
            locations <- standRef.region[which((standRef.region$location > sample.region$begin[i]) & (standRef.region$location < sample.region$finish[i])),]

            # fill select indices of sed with the ith row of the sed column of sample.region, 
            sed[end_tracker:(end_tracker + nrow(locations))] <- sample.region$sed[i]    

            # update end_tracker to the number of locations rows for this iteration
            end_tracker <- end_tracker + nrow(locations)                
        }
        cat("Finished region", region,"\n")            
    }       
    # fill in next, unfilled column of relevant df with data from relevant vector
    sediment.df[col_counter] <- sed   

    # update column counter variable 
    col_counter <- col_counter + 1
}       

# save df as a table
write.table(sediment.df,file="samples_sed.txt", row.names=TRUE, sep="\t") 
}
```

Running `Rprof` showed that 
`"scan" "read.table" "matchLocationsToRegions"` and
`"type.convert" "read.table" "matchLocationsToRegions"`
predominate runtime. Presumably, there's a bottleneck by for-looping over this line:

```
sample <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

NB: I've also posted this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Closing as a [duplicate on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8691966/420055).